# Why do some of the Ubuntu Docker images have a .1 on the date based tag?

Tags: docker

The Ubuntu Docker [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/) have date based tags for most builds.  However, some of them have a `.1` appended to the end.  For example, `xenial-20180123` vs `xenial-20180112.1`.  What does the `.1` mean?